# Combine ifelse two conditions and loop

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have a liste of dataframes (file1, file2, ..., file 72). For each dataframe I want to create one variable containing information from another dataframe based on two conditions.

The idea is simple:

- condition 1: if file*$countryid equals source$country, and
- condition 2: if file*$year is higher than source$starting but lower than source$ending, then if true I want to create a column file*$rank with the value in source$rank

I have been trying code lines like this but this code does not go through all lines in source:

```
file1$rank<-ifelse(file1$countryid=source$countryid & file1$year>source$starting & file1$year<source$ending,source$rank,NA)
```

In addition I would like to implement this within a loop to avoid iterating manually through all these dataframes:

```
dflist<-Filter(is.data.frame, mget(ls()))
dflist<-function(df,x){df$rank<-ifelse(df$countryid=source$countryid & df$year>source$starting & df$year<source$ending,source$rank,NA))
```

Here is an example of the data I have.
Thank you!

```
> dput(file1)
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), countryid = c(10, 10, 13), year = c(1948, 
1954, 1908)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

```
dput(file2)
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), countryid = c(13, 10, 13), year = c(1907, 
1908, 1907)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

```
> dput(source)
structure(list(country = c(13, 13, 13, 10, 10, 10), rank = c(1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3), starting = c(1885, 1909, 1940, 1902, 1907, 1931
), ending = c(1908, 1939, 1960, 1906, 1930, 1960)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a non-equi join after getting all the `file\\d+` datasets into a `list`

```
library(data.table)
out <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = '^file\\d+$')), function(dat) 
   setDT(dat)[, year := as.integer(year)][as.data.table(source), rank := i.rank, 
      on = .(countryid = country, year > starting, year < ending)])
```

-output

```
out
#$file1
#   id countryid year rank
#1:  1        10 1948    3
#2:  2        10 1954    3
#3:  3        13 1908   NA

#$file2
#   id countryid year rank
#1:  1        13 1907    1
#2:  2        10 1908    2
#3:  3        13 1907    1
```

---

if it needs to update the original objects, use `list2env`

```
list2env(out, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Hi @akrun this looks great. One small thing I had not realized is that year in file* are stored as chr and not as num as in the source file. How can I proceed in that case?

Comment: @MarcelCampion I made the change to convert to integer in the function